# How to bind Mesos services to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I want mesos to start **my** services on a different interface.

Right now, it can only bind to `0.0.0.0`, and my host is accessible to the outside.

I have tried to play with `LIBPROCESS_IP` as recommended in the doc, but I couldn't make it work.

Edit :

Mesos is already starting it's **own** services on a private interface, I am writing about the services I want start on marathon, they all get binded to **0.0.0.0**

Answer (score 3):

You could start mesos with `--ip` to bind it to `127.0.0.1`. For example, bind `mesos-master` to `127.0.0.1`:

```
mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos
```

Or bind `mesos-slave` to `127.0.0.1`:

```
mesos-slave.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/tmp/emsos
```

Comment: This is not working. It only change the ip mesos expose it's slave and master when it start.

Comment: In my test, it only bind to 127.0.0.1 when I specify 127.0.0.1
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26762/mesos-master

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit your tests ? I don't see the point your trying to prouve ? Did you manage to bind the started app on another interface ? I have heard LIBPROCESS_IP can help.

Comment: I just execute mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1, and LIBPROCESS_IP have same effects.